# Random password access to webpages on Chrome

Tags: python, google-chrome, random, automation, passwords

I recently watch a video which outlined the 20 second rule, the idea is that we can disrupt and eventually break bad habits if we can find ways to create at least a 20 second buffer between when we would like to use it and when we can actually access it. I find myself all the time working on project, running into a bug then just getting on Facebook for half an hour. So, I came up with the idea of creating a program which randomly generates a password to access Facebook, to get the password, you must run python program which prompts for 20 inputs then it will give you the password, it will then reset the password for the next session. I have been thinking about this the past week and looking a chrome extensions and the like but I still have no idea how to go about it. Does anyone have any idea of the starting point or how you would go about it?

Comment: Chrome extensions sounds like a good place to start. In order to change passwords in sites like Facebook, Twitter, etc. You will have to use their own API. I suggest you start by learning about Chrome extensions and the Facebook API to see if, and how, you can change a single password automatically. Once you'll know how to change a single password, the distance to an automatic password-changing extensions will be much shorter.

Comment: Do you think it would be easier to look at putting a password on the webpage of Facebook or to automatically log out of Facebook and change the password each use? I'm just wondering if it's possible to avoid having to use the Facebook API.

Comment: I have a better idea for you if you want to avoid accessing a given site for X minutes - you can add a firewall rule preventing access from the site, and then remove it whenever you want (let's say, after 20 minutes). You can use Chrome extensions for that, or you can write a script that sniffs the network and searches for HTTP `GET` requests for specific sites. How does that sounds?

Comment: The advantage of this solution is that it's generic and does not depends on APIs of sites.